# How can I enable thumbnails on Xubuntu desktop?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, thumbnails, thunar

I can't see any thumbnails on my desktop. If I use Thurnar directly and browse to the desktop, thumbnails of PDf, JPG and ODT are displayed, but on my desktop its just plain.
How can I fix that? I'm facing the problem on 2 different Laptops.

Comment: did u try restarting? @ph1b

Comment: Several times. It didnt work since I installed xubuntu on both machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on you desktop and select `Desktop Settings`.

Under `Icons` tab, Enable `Show thumbnails`.

[image]

That's it!